# Self join insted of loop

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table like below

```
DocNo       Account ExRate  Amount
65000071    5666    null    1000
65000072    5666    4.3     -290
65000073    5666    5.9     -290
65000074    5667    null    4500
65000075    5667    null    -500
65000076    5667    2.3     -500
65000077    5667    1.6     -500
65000078    5668    null    3450
65000079    5668    7.4     -453
65000080    5668    8.1     -453
65000081    5668    8.4     -453
65000082    5668    7.9     -453
 65000081   5669    8.4     -453
    65000082    5669    7.9     -453
```

I need to apply exchange rates. Only 1st transaction exrate need to be picked. below is the output

```
DocNo   Account ExRate  Amount  
65000071    5666    null    1000    
65000072    5666    4.3    -1247    (-290*4.3)
65000073    5666    5.9    -1247    (-290*4.3)
65000074    5667    null    4500    
65000075    5667    null    -500    
65000076    5667    2.3     -500    
65000077    5667    1.6     -500    
65000078    5668    null    3450    
65000079    5668    7.4  -3352.2    (-453*7.4)
65000080    5668    8.1  -3352.2    (-453*7.4)
65000081    5668    8.4  -3352.2    (-453*7.4)
65000082    5668    7.9  -3352.2    (-453*7.4)
65000081     5669   8.4     -453
65000082    5669    7.9     -453
```

For doing this, write now I worte while loop. But it is taking too loog. Can we do this using joins. Thank you.

Comment: What's the logic? Why was no exchange rate applied to account 5667?

Comment: @Barmar exchange rate was not applied to 5667, because 1st recovery transaction <<65000075    5667    null    -500>> doesn’t have exchange rate.

Comment: But first transaction 65000071 for account 5666 doesn't have exchange rate, and you did apply the exchange rate to transactions 65000072 and 65000073. What's the difference?

Comment: Is it just the transactions with negative Amount that we have to apply exchange rate to?

Comment: @Barmar +ve amounts are advances taken, they will not have exchange rates. –ve amounts are recoveries and only these transactions will have exchange rate. Out of these –ve amount transactions we need to pic first transaction exchange rate and multiply to remaining recovery transactions. For an account if exchange rate is not available for 1st –ve transaction then don’t multiply anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  tbl.DocNo, tbl.Account, tbl.ExRate,
        CASE WHEN tbl.Amount < 0 THEN (tbl.Amount * t.NewExRate)
            ELSE tbl.Amount END
        AS NewAmount
FROM table tbl
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT  t1.Account,
                        CASE WHEN tMin.MaxAmount >= 0 THEN ISNULL(t1.ExRate,1)
                            ELSE 1 END
                        AS NewExRate
                FROM    table t1
                LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT t2.Account,MIN(t2.DocNo) AS MinDocNo,tMax.MaxAmount
                                FROm    table t2
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT t3.Account,MAX(t3.Amount) AS MaxAmount
                                            FROm    table t3
                                            GROUP BY t3.Account)tMax
                                ON t2.Account = tMax.Account
                                WHERE   t2.Amount < 0
                                GROUP BY t2.Account, tMax.MaxAmount
                                ) tMin
                ON t1.Account = tMin.Account
                WHERE t1.DocNo = tMin.DocNo
                )t
ON tbl.Account = t.Account
```

Comment: thanks for the answe. but for a case like, account without any advance (+ve amount) we should not apply exchange rate. I edited my table <<Account 5669>>. But query is appling exchange rate.

Comment: I am getting following error <<Column 'tMax.MaxAmount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.>>

Comment: sorry for that. I've added `tMax.MaxAmount` in the `GROUP BY` clause now.

Answer (score 0):

```
select DocNo, t.Account as Account, t.ExRate as ExRate,
       case when Amount >= 0 then Amount
            else Amount * coalesce(t1.ExRate, 1)
       end as Amount
from MyTable as t
left outer join
     (select m.Account as Account, ExRate
      from MyTable as t
      join (select Account, min(DocNo) as MinDoc
            from MyTable
            where ExRate is not null and Amount < 0
            group by Account) as m
      on t.DocNo = m.MinDoc) as t1
on t.Account = t1.Account
order by DocNo
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it is appling exchange rate to 5667 account too.